# Django rest framework: catch ValidationError from external package

Tags: python, django, exception, django-rest-framework

I'm using the [`django-rest-passwordreset`](https://github.com/anx-ckreuzberger/django-rest-passwordreset) package to implement password reset endpoints. 
When a given email doesn't exist, it throws a `ValidationError` exception, causing a 500 error. How can I catch this error, and return a 400 instead? I simply added the urls as shown below, so I don't think I can surround it with an `try: except` or something similar.

> urlpatterns=[
>   ...
>   url(r'^password/recover/', include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls')),
>   ...
>   ]

Exception:

> ValidationError at /password/recover/
>   {'email': ['There is no active user associated with this e-mail address or the password can not be changed']}
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL: http://192.168.99.100:8000/password/recover/
>   Django Version: 2.0.6
>   Traceback:
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
>     35.             response = get_response(request)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
>     128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
>     126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
>     54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
>     69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
>     483.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
>     443.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
>     480.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_rest_passwordreset/views.py" in post
>     116.                     code='invalid')}
>   Exception Type: ValidationError at /password/recover/
>   Exception Value: {'email': ['There is no active user associated with this e-mail address or the password can not be changed']}
>   Request information:
>   USER: AnonymousUser
>   GET: No GET data
>   POST: No POST data
>   FILES: No FILES data
>   COOKIES: No cookie data
>   HEADERS: "email" : "bob@thebuilder.com"

Comment: `ValidationError` should throw 400 not 500. Can you post the exception message together with traceback?

Comment: error 500 occurs when your url is incorrect and cannot find the view.

Comment: can I see your urls.py file?

Comment: @mariodev: Added the ValidationError traceback. The relevant urlpattern is already there, and works fine for correct email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by creating a custom Exception handler as described [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling).
Additional information:
- Filter on the specific error message to avoid catching ALL ValidationErrors,
- Otherwise return the standard Django exception response.

Comment: I think you better make it manually to reset the password